# Do all browser support progressive image display?

Tags: browser

Do all browsers support progressive image display?

Comment: Define "progressive". There are two types of progressive. One is to show the data as it is recieved; the other, the picture gradually getting less and less blurry.

Comment: @Hello71: There is also the option to show a low-res compressed image as soon as possible and then replace it with a large uncompressed file once it has loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Not all browsers support it, but the most current versions of most popular browsers such as Firefox, Opera and IE do. I know Opera 6 for example did not support progressive rendering.

Here's a [link to all supported formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support)

Comment: do u know any link about this info?

Comment: @ivo -i'm not talking about image format support i'm talking about progressive image display.

Comment: althout this link has "Internet Explorer does not support progressive display of progressive JPEG."

Comment: @Jitendra: It doesn't display it progressively, but that doesn't mean IE won't display the image at all. It will still display it, but it will wait until after the entire image is loaded. However, I believe this was only a problem in IE6 and earlier versions.